# 'Multiclass-multioutput is not supported' Error in Scikit learn for Knn classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I have two variables X and Y.

The structure of X (i.e an np.array):

```
[[26777 24918 26821 ...    -1    -1    -1]
[26777 26831 26832 ...    -1    -1    -1]
[26777 24918 26821 ...    -1    -1    -1]
...
[26811 26832 26813 ...    -1    -1    -1]
[26830 26831 26832 ...    -1    -1    -1]
[26830 26831 26832 ...    -1    -1    -1]]
```

The structure of Y :

```
[[1252, 26777, 26831], [1252, 26777, 26831], [1252, 26777, 26831], [1252, 26777, 26831], [1252, 26777, 26831], [1252, 26777, 26831], [25197, 26777, 26781], [25197, 26777, 26781], [25197, 26777, 26781], [26764, 25803, 26781], [26764, 25803, 26781], [25197, 26777, 26781], [25197, 26777, 26781], [1252, 26777, 16172], [1252, 26777, 16172]]
```

The array in Y , example [1252, 26777, 26831] are three separate features.

I am using Knn classifier from scikit learn module

```
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
classifier.fit(X,Y)
predictions = classifier.predict(X)
print(accuracy_score(Y,predictions))
```

But I get an error saying :

> ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported

I guess the structure of 'Y' is not supported , what changes do I make in order for the program to execute?

Input :

```
  Deluxe Single room with sea view
```

Expected Output :

```
c_class = Deluxe
c_occ = single
c_view = sea
```

Comment: can you share what the input and output actually are? like is it an image data or what are the input and output features?

Comment: Have added the input and expected output ,its all text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the error, `KNN` does not support multi-output regression/classification.

For your problem, you need [**`MultiOutputClassifier()`**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputClassifier.html).

```
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(knn, n_jobs=-1)
classifier.fit(X,Y)
```

Working example:

```
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
>>> corpus = [
...     'This is the first document.',
...     'This document is the second document.',
...     'And this is the third one.',
...     'Is this the first document?',
... ]
>>> vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
>>> X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

>>> Y = [[124323,1234132,1234],[124323,4132,14],[1,4132,1234],[1,4132,14]]

>>> from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
>>> from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
>>> knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
>>> classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(knn, n_jobs=-1)
>>> classifier.fit(X,Y)
>>> predictions = classifier.predict(X)

array([[124323,   4132,     14],
       [124323,   4132,     14],
       [     1,   4132,   1234],
       [124323,   4132,     14]])

>>> classifier.score(X,np.array(Y))
0.5

>>> test_data = ['I want to test this']
>>> classifier.predict(vectorizer.transform(test_data))
array([[124323,   4132,     14]])
```

Comment: I am getiing the same error ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported

Comment: Strange, did you change the knn classifier name? can you share the complete traceback of the error?

Comment: The Y variable ain't a np array, it is comma separated , could that be the reason?

Comment: i added these two lines and I get the same error : predictions = classifier.predict(X)
#print(accuracy_score(Y,predictions))

Comment: `predictions` does not give any error. You cannot use `accuracy_score` for multi-output, you need to apply it individual for each column of the output

Comment: so suppose if I want the percentage of accuracy ,how could I do that?

Comment: Use this `classifier.score(X,np.array(Y))`.

Comment: Thanks,and if I want to give a new input so that the program could give output based on previosly trained data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191153/discussion-between-ai-learning-and-justin-joy).

Answer (score 0):

```
#use dataframe instead of list:
#for example :
dataset = list()
#....
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)

y, X = df[df.columns[-1]], df.drop(df.columns[-1], axis=1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=42)

# euclidean_distance (l2) for p = 2.
knn_model = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,p=2)
knn_model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn_model.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print('Accuracy score: ', round(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred), 2))
print('F1 Score: ', round(f1_score(y_test, y_pred), 2))
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).