# Invalid shape error while using Knn Classfier

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, knn

Following are the `X` and `Y` variable shapes:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

## Output for shapes 
X_train.shape  = (970, 298) 
X_test.shape   = (478, 298)
len(y_train)   =  970
len(y_test)    =  478
```

Now I assign `Multi-output` classifier from `Knn` :

```
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
classifier = MultiOutputClassifier(knn, n_jobs=-1)
classifier.fit(X_train,y_train)

predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
print classifier.score(y_test,predictions)
```

When I try to run this,I get the following error:

> ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] ==
>   3 while Y.shape[1] == 298

Now I can make out that the error is something related to the shape of the variables, maybe I am mixing them while splitting them for training or testing.

Tried searching but to no avail, what mistake am I making?

Sample :

```
X = (0, 96) 0.24328157992528274
(0, 191)    0.4086854706249901
(0, 279)    0.3597892480519696
(0, 209)    0.6262243704015803
(0, 287)    0.15142673105175225
(0, 44) 0.2839334104854308
(0, 31) 0.27493029497336746
(0, 62) 0.2702778021025414

Y  =[1252, 12607, 12596], [12480, 12544, 12547], [1252, 12607, 12547], [12480, 12607, 12547], [12480, 12607, 12596], [1252, 12607, 12547], [12480, 12544, 12547], [1252, 12607, 12596], [1252, 12607, 12596], [12480, 12544, 12547], [12480, 12607, 12596]
```

Comment: Why are you using a multi-output classifier, when your train and test data only has a single output in your `y` vectors? Are you perhaps confusion multi-output with multiclass output?

Comment: this is the previous question that i had posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55489792/multiclass-multioutput-is-not-supported-error-in-scikit-learn-for-knn-classifi/55491452?noredirect=1#comment97692433_55491452 , kindly view that

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your `X` and `Y` data?

Comment: done , kindly check the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`Documentation:`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.score)

```
Returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels.

In multi-label classification, this is the subset accuracy which is a harsh metric since you require for each sample that each label set be correctly predicted.

Parameters: 
X : array-like, shape = (n_samples, n_features)
Test samples.

y : array-like, shape = (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
True labels for X.

sample_weight : array-like, shape = [n_samples], optional
Sample weights.

Returns:    
score : float
Mean accuracy of self.predict(X) wrt. y
```

Hence, you need to give `X`, `y` for the score function and not `y_true` and `y_pred`

Try:

```
print classifier.score(X_test, np.array(y_test))
```

Comment: I get this : AttributeError:  if y.ndim == 1:
 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'